# How to loop through an integer and extract another shorter integer (from left to right)?

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, integer

I have to obtain two positive integers from the user (one longer and one shorter). Then I have to loop through the longer integer (from left to right) and to check to see if the shorter integer appears inside the longer integer. And I have to report the position of the matches and the number of matches.

***I am not allowed to use strings and list to do this ):**

```
# Ask user for positve longer integer number
import math

longInt = int(input("Input a positive longer integer: "))

# Ask user for positive shorter integer number 
shortInt = int(input("Input a positive shorter integer: "))

# Count number of digits in both longer and shorter integer numbers
longLength = int(math.log10(longInt)) + 1
shortLength = int (math.log10(shortInt)) + 1

for offset in range(longLength):
    subInt = longInt // 10 ** offset % 10 ** shortLength
    print(subInt)
    if subInt == shortInt:
        print("Found a match at position ", offset)
```

So the result I get is:

```
Input a positive longer integer: 123456
Input a positive shorter integer: 12
56
45
34
23
12
Found a match at position  4
1
```

But how do I get it to loop through the `long_int` from left to right instead of right to left? Like this:

```
Input a positive longer integer: 123456
Input a positive shorter integer: 12

1
12
Found a match at position  1
23
34
45
56
```

Please do help! Thanks!

Comment: *I am not allowed to use strings and list to do this*. Oh don't you love arbitrary homework restrictions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep. So `bytearray` is permitted then :)

Comment: @gnibbler: as are tuples!

Comment: @MartijnPieters, but you can't just use `in` for tuples

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ btw

Comment: @gnibbler: You can if you chop up the number into `shortInt` length pieces. Not that it'd be any better..

Comment: @ErikAllik: Please don't apply a style guide to questions and answers. Style guides are a guideline, not a rule. You are hindering question askers in translating the code to their own project.

Comment: So you reverted my entire edit? It also contained very useful edits :) And actually that "hindrance" is meant to be educational—to make them notice.

Comment: @ErikAllik Your edit was a radical change.

Comment: I think "radical change" actually means something that changes the meaning/point/essence of the post; converting from `camelCase` to `under_scores` doesn't change the meaning/point/essence of anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the `offset` from `longLength` to count 'backwards':

```
for offset in range(longLength):
    subInt = longInt // 10**(longLength - offset - 1) % 10**(shortLength)
```

Comment: I could not identify with the syntax. Which language is this?

Comment: @MMss: Uhm, take a look at the tags on the question? It's Python.

Comment: Python 3 to be precise—`//` is not typically found in Python 2 code, which is perhaps why the confusion.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters! (: Do you know how I can start the result subInt with '12' instead of '1'?

Comment: @JanL: Subtract the `shortLength` instead of `1`, and adjust your `range()` to loop to `range(longLenth - shortLength + 1)`.